# Programmatically changing the root controller of an UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm using storyboard and I have set an `UITabBarController` as the root controller. I have 3 tab items in the tab bar, and for the first one, I have an `UINavigationController`. I want the root view controller of this navigation controller to be dinamically set: I have two view controller candidates depending on a parameter provided by the user.

I'm trying to do like this in `AppDelegate`:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
if (condition1) {
    UINavigationController *navViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navController"];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController1"];
    [navViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]];

} else if (condition2) {
    UINavigationController *navViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navController"];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController2"];
    [navViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]];
```

But it does not work. In the storyboard, I don't have any segue neither for `homeController1 nor`homeController2`. How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what is happening that is different than what you are expecting? Have you verified that all of the variables are non-nil?

Comment: @oltman It means that view controllers are not loaded... yes, I've checked that I get non-nil references when I instantiate from the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to launch a different view controller depending on a condition. You can try this in your app delegate.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard =
  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

if (yourCondition) {
    UIViewController *viewController =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tutorialView"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
} else {
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm trying to do, except for the fact that the conditional view controllers are not the `window.rootViewController`... but no view controller is loaded by using the code I posted...